# How to explicitly reference global functions?

Tags: javascript

How can I reference a global function, in the case where using its name would refer to e.g. a local variable instead?

Take this simple example of a recursion:

```
function foobar(foobar) {
    return foobar(foobar+1); //<- error in this line
}
```

This would yield the error "foobar is not a function", as the same name is defined as parameter. How can I explicitly reference the function without renaming either the function nor the parameter?
I tried

```
function foobar(foobar) {
    return Window.foobar(foobar+1);
}
```

without success.

Comment: `window` doesn't start with a capital letter.

Comment: Just rename it... Unless you have a real use case. I guess you can use `arguments.callee` (does not work in strict mode)

Comment: I consider it best practise to provide the minimum code needed to reproduce the error. So why the close-votes?

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."*

Comment: Is this a real world problem? If so, could you give context? Clearly *"don't overwrite your own variables"* is the obvious answer, so there must be something more going on. Is this generated code, so you can't know what the names will be ahead of time?

Comment: This ist a real-world-problem in a Javascript based frontend-testing framework currently under development. "function assert(assert) {" occures, as assert is both the name of the object containing an assert and the name of the function evaluating the assert. Yet again: The question title stated the question in a clear matter, so that after 30 seconds Juhanas comment held the solution.

Answer (score 0):

as @Juhana stated this will work and you will get an `Exception: InternalError: too much recursion` as expected

```
function foobar(foobar) {
    return window.foobar(foobar+1);
}
foobar(3);
```

Comment: This won't work if this is in a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

Comment: Thanks. It was just the minimum code required to reproduce the error message. Lowercasing window did solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named function expression. Use function name (`recursive`) inside the function. From the outside the function is assigned to the variable with the name `foobar`:

```
var foobar = function recursive(foobar) {
    return recursive(foobar + 1);
}

foobar(5);
```